# Basic XML to HTML conversion

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I have what is hopefully a simple issue to debug.  Using code from a book and a website I am trying to convert my XML file to an HTML file.  However, I am getting no output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting"/>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="greeting">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>hellowWorld.xsl</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </h1>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

. . . is the XSL, here is the XML:

```
<root>
<greeting>
        Hello, world!
    </greeting>
</root>
```

And the code:

```
private static void XMLtoHTML(String xmlPath, String xslPath, String htmlPath)
{
try 
{
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformer =
  tFactory.newTransformer
     (new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
        (xslPath));

transformer.transform
  (new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
        (xmlPath),
   new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
        ( new FileOutputStream(htmlPath)));
}
catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try changing `<xsl:apply-templates select="greeting"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="root/greeting"/>`

Comment: Doh! I had an autogenerated root tag that I didn't account for.  This works!  If you can submit this as an answer, I will select it!

Comment: Answer added. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<xsl:apply-templates select="greeting"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="root/greeting"/>`.